# Autolink phone won't work

Tags: android, textview

I have this layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="20dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/order_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:autoLink="phone"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/order"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/about_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/about_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="@string/about" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tarrifs_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tarrifs_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="@string/tarrifs" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in textview order_content i put string:
"
\r\n
11-22-33
8 999 333 11 22 \r\n
8 888 444 22 33 \r\n
"
two phone numbers except first is colored(blue color and underline), but i can't to click them and to call, can somebody to help me?
p.s. sorry for my english

SOLVE - to comment line : tv_order.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem line: tv_order.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());